# Storing unix timestamp versus string with UTC

Tags: time, utc, epoch, iso8601

I have a conversation today with my engineering coworkers about application and database design in Fintech.

How do we handle time?  We all know that we need to store the datetime information normalized in UTC. But our debate is among whether we should store in 1) unix epoch timestamp which is an integer in our database, for example, `1596507157`. which is `08/04/2020 @ 2:12am UTC`  or 2) store in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format in string `2020-08-04T02:12:37+00:00` or `2020-08-04T02:12:37.123456789Z`

The downside of unix timestamp is obviously not immediate human-readable.

I am here looking for some design advices on whether we should adopt either approach.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you should store it as integer rather than string, one of many reasons is obvious, int just needs 4 byte while string as ISO 8601 takes a lot more.

What you see as downside, it doesn't impact the backend, it's just a make up (only needed on user view).

Answer (score 0):

Most of database have datetime data type. I guess your 'epoch timestamp' means this datetime or timestamp data type. It's easier (and better performance) to handle datetime type for database engineer. and database also have datetime formatting function.
(Oracle/MS SQL Server - convert, MySQL - date_format, PostgreSQL - to_char ...)

In my opinion, store and handle with datetime type and use formatting function for human.